# Save() method thread safe or not in django

Tags: django, thread-safety, python-3.6

Is django's save method thread safe or not. Meaning that if i have multiple threads then will the save() method interfere with the data sent to each of the save() method ? Have faced this problem while running the save() method on multiple threads. I noticed that some of the fields values are interchanged meaning that the field value of one thread's save method has gone to the field value of the other thread. Is there a way to tackle with this situation?

```
from project.views import start_new_thread
from django.db import connection
@start_new_thread
def site(site,loop):
 try:
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 from django.db.models import Max
 import re
 import pytz
 from datetime import datetime
 from .sentiment_analysis import calculate_sentiment
 import aiohttp
 import asyncio
 import async_timeout
 from project.models import thread,post
 import dateparser
 href=[]
 link=set()
 tthread=[]
 author={}

 def convert_si_to_number(x):
      total_stars = 0
      if 'K' in x:
         if len(x) > 1:
             total_stars = float(x.replace('K', '')) * 1000 # convert k to a thousand
      elif 'M' in x:
          if len(x) > 1:
              total_stars = float(x.replace('M', '')) * 1000000 # convert M to a million
      elif 'B' in x:
          total_stars = float(x.replace('B', '')) * 1000000000 # convert B to a Billion
      else:
          total_stars = int(x) # Less than 1000

      return int(total_stars)

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with async_timeout.timeout(30):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def forum(response,lockhref,lockthread):
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html5lib')
   table = soup.findAll('a',href=re.compile("forums/"))

   for row in table:
       url ='site.com'+row['href']
       async with lockhref:
            if url not in link:
                 href.append(url)
                 link.add(url)

   Th = soup.findAll('div',{'class':re.compile('structItem structItem--thread')})
   for t in Th:
       json_data={}
       divs=t.findAll("div")
       url="site.com"+(divs[2].div.find('a',href=re.compile('threads/')))['href']
       json_data["id"]=url
       dl=divs[5].findAll("dl")
       json_data["views"]=convert_si_to_number(dl[1].dd.text)
       f=thread.objects.filter(id=url)
       async with lockthread:
            if url not in link:
                 link.add(url)
                 if not len(f):
                      tthread.append(url)
                 else:
                      try:
                           if f[0].posts<convert_si_to_number(dl[0].dd.text)+1:
                                    tthread.append(url)
                      except:
                           if f[0].posts<1:
                                      tthread.append(url)       
       json_data["thread_title"]=divs[2].div.a.text
       json_data["site"]="site.com"
       json_data["posts"]=0
       json_data["timestamp_ms"]=None
       json_data["author"]=None
       json_data["date_created"]=None
       if not len(f):              

    t=thread(id=json_data["id"],thread_title=json_data["thread_title"],posts=json_data["posts"]                  ,views=json_data["views"],site=json_data["site"],timestamp_ms=json_data["timestamp_ms"],              
  author=json_data["author"],date_created=json_data["date_created"])

            t.save()

       elif f[0].views<json_data["views"]:                                                                                                      
thread.objects.filter(id=json_data["id"]).update(views=json_data["views"])           

  async def showthread(url,j,lock):
     async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
      try:
          response = await fetch(session, url)
          await threa(response,lock,url)

      except (aiohttp.ClientConnectionError,aiohttp.ClientConnectorError):
          print("Going to sleep for 5min")
          await asyncio.sleep(300)
          await showthread(url,j,lock)                   

      except asyncio.TimeoutError :
          print("Timeout Retrying")
          await showthread(url,j,lock)   

      except Exception as e:
          if j<2:
              j+=1
              print("error "+url+" "+str(e))
              await showthread(url,j,lock)

async def threa(response,lock,url):
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html5lib')
   table = soup.findAll('a',href=re.compile(url+"page-\d+"))
   for row in table:
        async with lockthread:
            if "site.com"+row["href"] not in link:
                tthread.append("site.com"+row["href"])
                link.add("site.com"+row["href"]) 

   table = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'message-inner'})
   match=re.finditer("page",url)
   index=-1
   for m in match:
         index=m.start()
   if index==-1:
         id=url
   else:
         id=url[:index]

   count=0
   for t in table:
        count=count+1
        json_data={}
        h4=t.find("h4",{'class':'message-name'})
        try:
            json_data["screen_name"]=h4.text
        except:
            json_data["screen_name"]="None"
        div=t.find('div',{'class':'message-attribution-main'})
        try:
           json_data["created_at"]=dateparser.parse(' '.join(div.text.split()))
           json_data["created_at"]=pytz.utc.localize(json_data["created_at"])
        except Exception as e:
           print(str(e)) 
           json_data['created_at']=datetime(1970, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,pytz.UTC)
        json_data['timestamp_ms']= datetime.timestamp(json_data['created_at'])

        div=t.find('div',{'class':'bbWrapper'})
        try:
            full_text=''.join((div.text).split())
        except:
            full_text=''
        text,sentiment=calculate_sentiment('ar',full_text)
        json_data['sentiment_analysis']=sentiment
        json_data["text"]=full_text
        json_data["cleaned_text"]=text.split()
        json_data["hashtags"]=''
        json_data["id"]=id
        try:
            ul=t.find('ul',{'class':re.compile('message-attribution-opposite')})
            li=ul.find('a',{'class':'qimahostma'})
            no=int((li.text).replace("#",''))
        except:
            f=post.objects.filter(link=id)
            if not len(f):
                 no=1
            else:
                 max=f.aggregate(Max('no'))
                 no=max['no__max']+1

        if int(no)==1:
               json_data["quoted_screen_name"]=''
               json_data["is_quote"]=False
               author[url]=json_data["screen_name"]
               thread_existing,created=thread.objects.get_or_create(id=json_data["id"])
               if created:
                   thread_existing.date_created=json_data["created_at"]
                   thread_existing.timestamp=json_data["timestamp_ms"]
                   thread_existing.author=json_data["screen_name"]
                   thread_existing.thread_title=(soup.find('h1',{'class':'p-title-value'})).text
                   thread_existing.posts=0
                   thread_existing.views=-1
                   thread_existing.site="site.com"
                   thread_existing.save()
               else:
                   thread_existing.thread_title=thread_existing.thread_title
                   thread_existing.posts=thread_existing.posts
                   thread_existing.views=thread_existing.views
                   thread_existing.site="site.com"
                   thread_existing.date_created=json_data["created_at"]
                   thread_existing.timestamp=json_data["timestamp_ms"]
                   thread_existing.author=json_data["screen_name"]
                   thread_existing.save()
        else:
               json_data["quoted_screen_name"]=author[url]
               json_data["is_quote"]=True

        json_data["no"]=int(no)
        json_data["site"]="site.com"
        try:
              p=post(link=json_data["id"],no=json_data["no"],created_at=json_data["created_at"],hashtags=[],text=json_data["text"],cleaned_text=json_data["cleaned_text"]
              ,sentiment_analysis=json_data["sentiment_analysis"],quoted_screen_name=json_data["quoted_screen_name"],is_quote=json_data["is_quote"],site=json_data["site"],
              timestamp_ms=json_data["timestamp_ms"],screen_name=json_data["screen_name"])
              p.save()
        except Exception as e:
              print(e)

   if count>0:  
           t=thread.objects.get(id=id)
           t.posts=t.posts+count
           t.save()


async def scrapping(url,j,lockhref,lockthread):
   async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
      try:
          response = await fetch(session, url)
          await forum(response,lockhref,lockthread)
      except (aiohttp.ClientConnectionError,aiohttp.ClientConnectorError):
          print("Going to sleep for 5min")
          await asyncio.sleep(300)
          await scrapping(url,j,lockhref,lockthread)        
      except asyncio.TimeoutError :
          print("Timeout Retrying")
          await scrapping(url,j,lockhref,lockthread)           
      except Exception as e:
           if j<2:
              j+=1
              print("error "+url+" "+str(e))
              await scrapping(url,j,lockhref,lockthread)

href.append("site.com/index.php")
link.add("site.com/index.php")
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
lockhref = asyncio.Lock()
lockthread=asyncio.Lock()
no_of_concurrent_connections=50
i=0
while i<len(href):
  if i+no_of_concurrent_connections<len(href):
       tasks=[loop.create_task(scrapping(href[j],0,lockhref,lockthread)) for j in range(i,i+no_of_concurrent_connections)]
       i+=no_of_concurrent_connections
  else:
     tasks=[loop.create_task(scrapping(href[j],0,lockhref,lockthread)) for j in range(i,len(href))]
       i=len(href)    
  loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))

i=0
while i<len(tthread):
  if i+no_of_concurrent_connections<len(tthread):
       tasks=[loop.create_task(showthread(tthread[j],0,lockthread)) for j in range(i,i+no_of_concurrent_connections)]
       i+=no_of_concurrent_connections

  else:
       tasks=[loop.create_task(showthread(tthread[j],0,lockthread)) for j in range(i,len(tthread))]
       i=len(tthread)    
  loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))

 finally:
      print('ended')
      connection.close()
```

These threads are created using a decorator

```
def start_new_thread(function):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        name=str(args[0])
        t = Thread(name=name,target = function, args=args, kwargs=kwargs,daemon=True)
        list[name]=t
        t.start()
    return decorator
```

Comment: Show your code. How are you using threads?

Comment: The Django ORM is thread-safe. But what you're talking about is a concurrency problem, where data in the database is changed by one process while it's being used in another process. Look at using [**F expressions**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f) to make sure your calculations use up-to-date data.

Comment: I'm quite surprised that you use threads in the first place, especially if you do ORM calls, you can perhaps parallelize the algorithm, but the ORM calls, is a bit "odd".

Comment: Have included the code now. Actually the code is a scraping code. I am creating an application in which when a user asks for scraping a site this example code will run in a parallel thread

Comment: if two threads run this code then some of the field are interchanged in the save method

Comment: for threading i use python's threading library.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by closing the connection whenever i created a new process or a thread and then on the new process django automatically created a new connection whenever it is needed